# Sensing a tag passes through a virtual "fence"

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-low-energy, nfc

We have two cats who like to hide in our house. It would be great to know where they are in the house. At first I thought about setting up an indoor localization system (iBeacon, etc.) in place, but those seem expensive.

So now I'm thinking that it would be good enough to know which part of the house they're in. There's a short hallway in our house that connects the two parts of the house together. I'm thinking about setting up two sensors, one on each side of the hallway, and put a tag (Bluetooth?) on the cats' collars. The sensor would send a message to the central system whenever the tag gets near it within, say, 50 cm. Would be great if the tag is passive.

Any idea on where I should start? Thanks!

Background: I have some experience with Arduino projects.

Comment: The cheapest is to spread sand and look for their footsteps. More seriously, i would go to a system of photointerrupters. A pair set up in a doorway would detect entrance/exit. Then control with some of the modern iot gadgets and report on a website.

Comment: Thanks! The problem with sand (and photointerrupters) is that people also use that hallway, so I'd like the sensors to track only the tags :(

Comment: Use a double set of photo interrupters at different heights : your cats are not 1m tall...

Comment: Track people too :) but next thing i would suggest, use third photointerrupter about 1m high to detect human.

Comment: You can also use video cameras. Cheap installation, tricky software. But very interesting.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum https://github.com/TucoFlyer will definitely be to your enjoyment ;) [There's a couple of videos online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JU6omrP2iFU) about this system which uses quite a lot of compute power to track ... a cat around a workshop, and potentially keep an automated flying (Delta-mounted) camera on it. (jump to minute 7 to see the tracking in action)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your requirements collide with your price expectations. Most active tags are heavy enough to annoy the cats. Passive tags have either too short range (e.g. 10 cm for RFIDs) or require high radiation readers (you don't want those in your house 24/7). And the readers are relatively expensive.

So, save money and go with IR photointerrupters as was suggested above. I'd put them in groups of 3, two near the floor to get direction and one higher to detect humans. Cheap and easy + some interesting programming.

Alternative would be to use PIR motion detectors. These give you a bit more flexibility in placement around house than photointerrupters. Ready made PIR modules can be found for just a couple bucks.

Comment: ha! You forget one basic technology: The stupid passive anti-theft tags and detectors that they use in stores. Cheap as dirt (quite literally).

Comment: Umm... they use RFIDs, which I mentioned in first paragraph. Yes, they cost almost nothing and probably can even be salvaged  from old DVD boxes. But reading them at anything > 10 cm requires _very_ expensive high RF power devices. Which I also mentioned. How much do you think those anti-theft gates in stores cost?

Comment: No, that's not true. They are not RFID. They are acousto-magnetic, and readers are dirt cheap, work across >2m and can be had as surplus equipment.

Comment: Ok, we are talking different devices here. The flat square ones with coil inside are RF tags, the rectangular plastic are acousto-magnetic, and I believe there are other types as well. Neither is uniquely-identifiable, which I assumed was a requirement. Of course if it isn't then this can be cheap alternative indeed.

Comment: Ah, unique identification would make sense, indeed! (and the optical gate methods described in the comments below the question don't have that, either)

Comment: Although neither of my proposed solutions provided that :(

Comment: You can measure cat's length with multiple photointerrupters. But it may be cheaper to lock the cat in one room.

Comment: Why not track the cats in 2 dimensions to cm level accuracy.  Maybe.  -  http://www.rfid-radar.com/

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth Low Energy Beacons were meant for exactly that kind of application! (or at least, very similar ones).

"BLE beacons" come in the shape of tags and run for weeks to months on coin cells, reach a couple of meters, and can be detected with any Bluetooth 4.0 or higher compatible USB dongle.

Your system would boil down to buying cheap BLE beacon tags, and distributing e.g. raspberry Pi Zeros in your house, equipped with appropriate USB bluetooth dongles. Add in software that periodically checks for visible Bluetooth devices, and something that combines observations into a cat state space estimator.

Comment: [interesting...](http://www.instructables.com/id/Cat-Tracking-using-Bluetooth-Indoor-Positioning/). Although the Gears they used are huge. There are tons of tiny "anti lost" beacons on the market.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy cheap bluetooth beacons from Alibaba or Aliexpress which pair with your mobile phone and make sound when you press a button on the app.

Link to such a device - https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Cheap-Price-Bluetooth-4-0-Eddystone_60538752951.html?spm=a2700.7724857.main07.23.634ef094XsZOQx

Answer (score 0):

You can use 4x pir sensors on each gate to get the readings. 2 on the upper portion to get if any person passes, and 2 on the lower portion to check if any living object is passing by there.[image]

if any man passes then all four will get activated. if any cat passes then lower ones will be active but not the upper ones. and 2 for each upper and lower part to detect the motion of cat from inside to outside or vice versa.